# Index for column1 = x AND column2 <= y ORDER BY column3 DESC

Tags: postgresql, types, indexing, query-optimization

I've googled, made 15 different indexes of different orders (including `interval_end, ticker, interval_start DESC`) and `ASC/DESC`, and ultimately the only one it uses is the `idx_onemin_intervalstart` one.  The `<=` operator is what is killing me I believe.

I've read all of the PostgreSQL manuals about indexes and am still baffled this wasn't an example.

#### QUERY

```
explain analyze 
SELECT open 
FROM  onemin_interval 
WHERE ticker = 'QQQ' 
  AND interval_end <= 1326810600000 
ORDER BY interval_start DESC 
LIMIT 19960;
```

#### TABLE SCHEMA

Table `public.onemin_interval`

```
   Column            |     Type      | Modifiers
---------------------+---------------+-----------
 interval_start      | numeric(13,0) | 
 interval_end        | numeric(13,0) |
 open                | numeric(10,2) |
 close               | numeric(10,2) |
 high                | numeric(10,2) |
 low                 | numeric(10,2) |
 volume_for_interval | bigint        |
 ticker              | character(10) |
 humantimeopen       | character(23) |
 humantimeclose      | character(23) |
 adlval              | bigint        |
```

#### Indexes

```
"idx_onemin_intervalend" btree (interval_end)
"idx_onemin_intervalend_intervalstart" btree (interval_end, interval_start)
"idx_onemin_intervalstart" btree (interval_start DESC)
"idx_onemin_ticker" btree (ticker)
"idx_onemin_ticker_intervalend" btree (ticker, interval_end)
```

#### QUERY PLAN

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..10295.29 rows=19960 width=20) (actual time=581.856..1731.352 rows=19960 loops=1)
->  Index Scan Backward using idx_onemin_intervalstart on onemin_interval  (cost=0.00..36843.32 rows=71430 width=20) (actual time=581.842..1621.713 rows=19960 loops=1)
     Filter: ((interval_end <= 1326810600000::numeric) AND (ticker = 'QQQ'::bpchar))
Total runtime: 1791.594 ms
(4 rows)
```

---

#### New content after comment

I added a ton of indexes for testing purposes, and ran `ANALYZE onemin_interval`. Query is almost the same as before:

```
explain analyze
SELECT open
FROM  onemin_interval
WHERE ticker = 'QQQ'
  AND interval_end <= 1327698068642
ORDER BY interval_start DESC
LIMIT 19960;
```

#### QUERY PLAN

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..5849.68 rows=19960 width=16) (actual time=0.088..394.596 rows=19960 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using test11 on onemin_interval  (cost=0.00..21748.74 rows=74210 width=16) (actual time=0.079..298.848 rows=19960 loops=1)
     Filter: ((interval_end <= 1327698068642::bigint) AND (ticker = 'QQQ'::text))
Total runtime: 1442.898 ms
(4 rows)
```

#### SCHEMA

Table `public.onemin_interval`

```
   Column           |     Type      | Modifiers
--------------------+---------------+-----------
interval_start      | bigint        |
interval_end        | bigint        |
open                | numeric       |
close               | numeric       |
high                | numeric       |
low                 | numeric       |
volume_for_interval | bigint        |
ticker              | text          |
humantimeopen       | character(23) |
humantimeclose      | character(23) |
adlval              | bigint        |
```

#### Indexes

```
"idx_onemin_intervalend" btree (interval_end)
"idx_onemin_intervalend_intervalstart" btree (interval_end, interval_start)
"idx_onemin_intervalstart" btree (interval_start)
"idx_onemin_ticker" btree (ticker)
"idx_onemin_ticker_intervalend" btree (ticker, interval_end)
"test1" btree (interval_end DESC)
"test10" btree (ticker, interval_end DESC, interval_start DESC)
"test11" btree (interval_start DESC)
"test12" btree (interval_start DESC, interval_end DESC, ticker)
"test13" btree (interval_start DESC, ticker, interval_end DESC)
"test14" btree (ticker, interval_start DESC, interval_end DESC)
"test15" btree (interval_end DESC, interval_start DESC, ticker)
"test3" btree (interval_end)
"test4" btree (interval_end DESC, ticker)
"test5" btree (interval_end, ticker)
"test6" btree (ticker, interval_end DESC)
"test7" btree (ticker, interval_end)
"test8" btree (interval_end, ticker)
"test9" btree (interval_end DESC, ticker, interval_start DESC)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to increase the performance of the query? How many rows does the table `onemin_interval` contain (in total)?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to improve the performance.  the table has 420k rows.  in particular i was hoping there was an index that would remove the "filter" that is happening after the index scan occurs

Comment: How many rows would be returned if you remove the `limit` clause?

Comment: The filter isn't happening after the index scan, the filter is the index scan.  That query plan says "I am going to read index "idx_onemin_intervalstart" to look for rows that satisfy the filter conditions "((interval_end <= 1326810600000::numeric) AND (ticker = 'QQQ'::bpchar))", which is precisely what you asked for.  There is no index problem here, you are just selecting 20,000 rows.

Comment: What **version** of PostgreSQL? This is essential for questions involving optimization and performance and should *always* be included to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, ~70k rows will be returned

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, version is 8.4.9

Comment: @SomeGuy, oh.  i guess that makes more sense now, i must have misread what it was doing from the manual.  perhaps i need to look at tweaking my conf file more.  shouldn't it however use a (interval_end,ticker) index as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Data types, size and performance

First of all, the type [**character(n)**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) is almost always a bad choice. If you don't have good reasons and know what you are doing, use the type [**`text`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html) instead. **If** you actually need to enforce a maximum length use a CONSTRAINT. Example for the column `ticker`:

```
ALTER TABLE onemin_interval
ADD CONSTRAINT onemin_interval_ticker_len CHECK (length(ticker) < 11);
```

Obviously you have values like 'QQQ', so a length of 10 seems arbitrary. This will reduce the table size (possibly dramatically) and speed up .. everything.

Also, consider using `bigint` instead of `numeric(13,0)`. You don't store fractional digits anyway, this is probably the superior design. [`numeric(13,0)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) requires 13 bytes (5 + 4x2), bigint needs 8 bytes and operations on it are faster in every respect.

And finally: can the `bigint` columns be plain `integer`, too? (If the range -2147483648 to +2147483647 is big enough over the course of the life time of the table.)

### Core problem

Why is index `idx_onemin_ticker_intervalend` not used?
I would try several things:

#### Explicit cast

If you cannot change the datatype to `text`, test the query with an explicit cast to `character(10)`:

```
WHERE ticker = 'QQQ'::character(10)
```

Older versions of PostgreSQL may not be able to use an index for `character(10)` for an unpadded string of three characters (`'QQQ'`). However, the index *is* used both in PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.1 in my tests.

#### Order of columns in multi-colukmn index

Try reverse the order of the columns in your multi-column index.

```
idx_onemin_ticker_intervalend btree (interval_end DESC, ticker)
```

[Order of the columns in a multi-column index *is* relevant](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6115/3684). Although, in your case, if everything would be in order it should be *irrelevant* as you include conditions on both columns. I would still test this.

#### Planner statistics

The query planner seems to expect the conditions `ticker = 'QQQ' AND interval_end <= 1326810600000` to be not very selective - while, in fact, they seem to be very selective (result 4 rows). Try raising the [default_statistics_target](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/planner-stats.html) for the two columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE onemin_ticker ALTER COLUMN interval_end SET STATISTICS 1000;
ALTER TABLE onemin_ticker ALTER COLUMN ticker SET STATISTICS 1000;
ANALYZE onemin_ticker;
```

Or even more, up to 10000 (you do have 420k rows). Default is 100. This usually only helps with uneven data ditribution, but with huge tables, it should pay off easily.

### General performance optimization

General advice for [performance optimization in the PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) always applies.

---

Finally, be aware that this kind of query can **never be lightening fast**. Sorting 70k rows takes time - and the engine has to sort *all* 70k rows before `LIMIT 19960` can be applied.

As I see from your update, the query planner uses index `test11 (interval_start DESC)` - which indicates that sorting is the most expensive operation in your query.

As you select by multiple criteria before you sort, I don't see a way how an index could further help you with that. Your data cannot be pre-sorted *and* pre-selected - except **if** the `WHERE` clause is stable, then you could create a partial index like:

```
CREATE INDEX onemin_interval_interval_start_part_idx
  ON    onemin_interval (interval_start DESC)
  WHERE ticker = 'QQQ'::character(10) 
  AND   interval_end <= 1326810600000
```

... resulting in lightening fat execution. But I don't suppose you get that lucky?
It would help a lot already, if one of the criteria was stable, so you can have a partial index on that one.

Comment: i want to first thank you for your help.  i went ahead and made the schema changes as suggested and read up on all of the Data Type section of the manual.  I cannot change all numeric to bigint due to precision for money.  Unfortunately it did not help as much as I thought it would (even after setting statistics to 1000 or more).  See below.  I'll leave this open for a few more days before closing the question, but in the mean time if you wanna look it over I'd appreciate it.

Comment: WRT your update:

Unfortunately i cannot create a partial index, as those values (ticker/interval_end) are variable and change as time increases.  As such I've restricted my LIMIT to be a maximum of 10,000 which results in a 150ms plan instead of the 1100~ms plan.

Thanks again!